# Master Details view with ionicframwork using ion-list

Tags: css, angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

i'm working on a ionic app and i need to use master details view ,so on small screen i show the list then when i click on item go to details (that is done ) , and for larger screen the list go side by side with details screen (check the images):

**Small Devices**

[image: Small device List screen]

[image: smal device details screen]

**Larger Devices**

[image: Small device List screen]

if any one can help me with an idea or he know how to do it I will be thankful.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: my question is how to do some think like this ?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to check the what the actual size of the device is. However, I do know how to check the size of the screen, you can do this by using `$window.innerWidth` and `$window.innerHeight`.

If you could find a way to get the pixel density of the screen, you would be able to calculate the size of the screen and then make it switch the view based on your calculation. You can do this by using `ng-if` on the content.

The reason why you're app looks the same on all phones is because the webview component where the ionic app runs in handles all the screen sizing.